# I need help making a program that will flip 2 coins at the same time

Tags: c++

```
for (int i = 0; i < input; ++i)
{
    if (rand() % 2 == 1)
    {
        cout << "H" << endl;
        heads++;
    }
    else(rand() % 2 == 2);
    {
        cout << "T " << endl;
        tails++;
    }
}
```

I've made a for loop but cant get the program to flip 2 coins so the response looks like this.

```
How many times would you like to flip the coins?

2

H T

H H
```

Comment: Make the else an else if.

Comment: would that make it have 4 (H/T) responses if i input 2 flips becasue its 2 coins flipping?

Comment: No. It is a syntax error. Also, any number mod 2 will **never** equal 2; it will be either 0 or 1. Do the rand calls outside of the if statement.

Comment: I'm confident that your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) will be glad to help you to figure out the logical problem with this code.

Comment: I also provided a very succinct way to do this using the ternary operator and the comma operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < input; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
    {
        if (rand() % 2 == 1)
        {
            cout << "H ";
            heads++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "T ";
            tails++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: how do i make it flip 2 coins?, so basically if i input 2 i get 4 results

Comment: Updated the example.

Comment: is there anyway I can find the percent a single coin had heads/tails? like if the result was HT--HH--TT--TH and the percent coin one was heads was 50% and Tails was 50%, then coin 2

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create two local variables that are assigned the random values and do two checks for each variable:

```
for(int i=0; i<input; ++i)
{
    int first_coin = rand();
    int second_coin = rand();
    (first_coin%2==0) ? (heads++, cout<<"H ") : 
                        (tails++, cout<<"T ");
    (second_coin%2==0) ? (heads++, cout<<"H ") : 
                         (tails++, cout<<"T ");
}
cout << endl;
```

You can run this example [here](http://ideone.com/9bEl0U).

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple mathematical error.  Modulus of anything can never equal any number higher than 0 or 1, so it will continue to print the '% == 1' statement when it shouldn't.

Comment: Correction. Modulus of anything with a number `N` can never equal any number higher than `N-1`. (ie. `4 % 3 == 1`).

Comment: Or a better example, `5 % 3 == 2`.